# Comparing Tract-level data to State-level?

Tags: census, social-science

I'm using firearm trace data (available at the state-level) and attempting to compare it to socially disadvantaged areas (census tracts) by the way of regression analysis. Katz and Schnebly (2011) used population characteristics of tracts to measure the relationship between socially disadvantaged areas and gang members and/or gang crime.

I want to be able to measure whether the number of firearms being recovered in a state that are sourced to a different state are dependent on socially disadvantaged areas (certain neighborhoods in urban areas). Assuming that most firearms are being recovered in large urban areas due to higher levels of firearm violence in cities. Since my DV is only at the state-level, **is there a meaningful way to generalize tract-level population characteristics to state-level?**

I realize that one method could be summarizing these characteristics, but I wasn't sure if there would be any variation lost between multiple urban areas in states.

There is no way to disaggregate the state trace data to counties or tracts.

> *Firearm Trace Data*
>   **Recovered**: (Factor) State where firearm was recovered and traced by law enforcement
>   **Year**: (Integer) Year when trace request was initiated
>   **Source**: (Factor) State where firearm was first purchased
>   **NumWeapons**: (Numerical) Number of firearms that were recovered in state (**Recovered**) and successfully traced to a state (**Source**) during **Year**

The socially disadvantaged data consist of index scores (factor analysis using rates of poverty, single-families, 25 and over w/o HS degree, etc.) for each census tract in a state by year.

Thank you.

Comment: Sure there is--but it depends on the nature of the data.  Could you describe what they are?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What exactly are you trying to do? Have you got tract level data for every tract in the state? Have you got data for more than one state? What do you mean by comparing firearm trace data to socially disadvantaged areas?

Comment: Peter, thanks for the questions, I tried clearing up my post. Data aren't available for every tract in a state, for instance tracts that include airports. However, I do have access to such data for multiple states.